# file transfer via bluetooth from IPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, file-transfer

In my app, i want to send a file to another iOS device via bluetooth.

I don't want to install any app from app store which using bluetooth functionality.

I want to implement bluetooth functionality in my app and once it connected means it would list out available iOS devices ( bluetooth enabled devices ) and send a file to selected device via bluetooth.

Is that possible? I don't know where to start..

Please help in this regards..if any sample code for it means its very helpful to me..

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GameKit is probably a good starting point as that supports peer-to-peer connectivity
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Not sure if the GameKit api's support sending files, and the documentation had this to say: Note: The largest message size allowed is 87 kilobytes. If you need to send more than that, you must split your data into multiple messages.

Here are some related questions as well:
[iPhone: Sending large data with Game Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212598/iphone-sending-large-data-with-game-kit)
[Send and receive NSData via GameKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837102/send-and-receive-nsdata-via-gamekit)
[Using GameKit to transfer CoreData data between iPhones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355694/using-gamekit-to-transfer-coredata-data-between-iphones)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the iOS CoreBluetooth Framework for this, where you can send any kind of data by converting it to NSData.

You can find Apple's demo project over here -> [Demo Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html)

PS: If you are not dealing with much complexities in your project, then you can also check this powerful library called [LGBluetooth](https://github.com/LGBluetooth/LGBluetooth) by l0gg3r on Github . Its pretty simple!

Cheers!

Comment: where is link ?

Comment: Not sure what happened to the links, I've updated the answer now.

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement OBEX protocol FTP (File Transport Profile) to pushing / pulling .... files from other device :) It is not easy to do !!